# Compare two Dataframes based on column value(String, Substring) and update another column value

Tags: pandas, string, loops, dictionary, apply

Dataframes df1,df2, where df1 Name column has a partial matching string on df2 Name column value. On the partial match of name column values, then compare the price column value of both data frames and if it is the same price then update  column(Flag) in df1 as 'Delete'

df1

| Name | Price | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VENTILLA HOME FARR | 662324.21 | Delete |
| VENTILLA HOME FARR | -277961.62 |  |
| VENTILLA HOME FARR | 776011.5 |  |
| VARAMANT METRO PLANET | 662324.21 |  |
| VARAMANT METRO PLANET | 55555.21 | Delete |
| VARAMANT METRO PLANET | 267117.5499 |  |
| FANTHOM STREET LLB | 83265.2799 |  |
| FANTHOM STREET LLB | -444452.96 | Delete |
| FANTHOM STREET LLB | 267117.5499 |  |

df2

```
my_dict = {'VT METRO PLANET  ': 267117.5499, 'VENTILLA HOME FA ': -277961.62, 'FANTHOM STREET ': 83265.2799}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.items()),columns = ['Name','Price'])
```

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If anyone needs more information, let me know

Comment: Yes, please use code or text to show your input dataframes.

Comment: @ScottBoston: Provided details in code and table

Comment: Can you make an estimate on how many unique "name" values there will be? If it's less than a few 1000, you can use `df1.Name.unique()` and `df2.Name.unique()` and then build a matching df where you can look up the match for later comparison. If it's a lot more than a few 1000 names, the time needed to build that comparison table will grow more and more... Once you have that df, you can first merge it with df1 (how="left") and merge the result with df2. And then update the Flag, because the merged table has both prices.

Comment: @576i  df1 has around 1100(unique 52) rows and 16 columns, df2 has 82(unique 14) rows and only 2 columns, For explanation, mentioned a limited sample

Answer (score 1):

the solution I share here for this problem is based on the **set**, so if the **Name** of **dataframe 1** is at least sharing one word with the **Name of dataframe 2**, and also their **Price** is equal then we edit the Flag column in the **dataframe 1** by **"Delete"** otherwise we made it as **"None"**

This The Code Source :

```
def check(row):
  df1_Name = set(map(lambda word: word.lower(),row.Name.split(' ')))
  df1_price = row.Price
  df1_flag = row.Flag

  for df2_Name, df2_Price in df2[['Name', 'Price']].values:
    df2_Name = set(map(lambda word: word.lower(),df2_Name.split(' ')))
    if len(df1_Name.intersection(df2_Name)) > 1 and df1_price  == df2_Price:
      return 'Delete'
  return '' 

df1["Flag"]= df1.apply(checkMatch,axis=1)
```

Comment: Instead of df1["Flag"] column, used an additional column df1["Flag1"] and returned value from a function.Later added the code `cond = df1["Flag"] == 'Delete' , df1['Flag'][cond] = df1['Flag1'][cond]`